# SQL Server 2008 datetime column JDBC insert problem

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have a table with a column that is a `DATETIME` in a SQL Server 2008 database.  The dates that are being inserted are not timestamps in the sense that using NOW on insert would be acceptable.  The date is generated a bit before the insert and I would like to preserve this value.

Datetimes are being serialized as strings in the format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.[fff...]` and then converted to a JDBC Timestamp object before being inserted.

A problem I'm running into with SQL Server is that it converts the value to TIMESTAMP before being inserted and then complains with this:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 
Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column. 
Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the timestamp column, 
or insert a DEFAULT into the timestamp column.
```

How can I just insert into a DATETIME column without the conversion?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that there is no column of type Timestamp in the table? As those look like SQL server error messages re timestamp not Java. - Show us the schema

Comment: 100%.  The question was answered already.  setString is what you want, not setTimestamp.  I guess each JDBC driver deals with datetimes in different ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A SQL Server TIMESTAMP data type is not a date-like data type.  It is a server-generated value used to help with data consistency.  If you are storing datetime data, then avoid the TIMESTAMP data type.

So, don't convert to a JDBC Timestamp object.  Data can be inserted as a string value.  Note that the format you indicate is okay, but the `fff...` must be 3 digits, not more than 3 digits for a SQL Server DATETIME data type.

Comment: That's why I was confused because I know I did not want a timestamp conversion (setTimestamp works with MySQL DATETIME types so it's confusing).  setString() works instead.  Thanks!

Comment: yep.  SQL Server TIMESTAMP is confusing, and the good news is that it's deprecated.  It is replaced by the ROWVERSION keyword, which should reduce confusion.

Comment: What I was most confused about is the lack of datetime support in jdbc.  You either get a Date, a Time, or a Timestamp, but not a Datetime.  setString isn't an obvious way to set a Datetime.

Comment: actually setString() is the *wrong* way of setting a "Datetime" it is error prone because of implicit date conversion and might not always work depending on your locale settings. A Timestamp is *exactly* what you want (it's just a different word for "datetime")

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, with SQL Server a TIMESTAMP is NOT a different word for DATETIME.  They are two very different data types.

Comment: @bobs: I know ;) but in JDBC Timestamp is a different word for DATETIME. I just wanted to point out that setString() is a bad idea and setTimestamp() is actually dealing with a "Datetime"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name well, that's what I was wondering.  MySQL and Postgres IIRC let you set their date time types using setTimestamp which would seem better for processing dates, but it could be that the JDBC driver for SQL Server correctly processes the date from a string and just doesn't support setTimestamp in the way I'm used to.

Comment: @Max: setTimestamp() *is* supported by the JDBC driver - just not for "timestamp" columns...

Comment: But it doesn't support datetimes unlike other drivers.  Does it just map directly to sql server's timestamp column?  If so that's fine, but the whole driver ecosystem is so varied it's frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

If the column is defined as a TimeStamp here's a quote from SQL Server Books Online:

> The SQL Server timestamp data type has
>   nothing to do with times or dates. SQL
>   Server timestamps are binary numbers
>   that indicate the relative sequence in
>   which data modifications took place in
>   a database. The timestamp data type
>   was originally implemented to support
>   the SQL Server recovery algorithms.
>
> It further states Never use timestamp
>   columns in keys, especially primary
>   keys, because the timestamp value
>   changes every time the row is
>   modified.

Comment: I said it wasn't defined as a timestamp but rather a datetime.