# sql server jdbc query on datetime column

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I've looked around and could not seem to find this asked specifically, on SO, but I've found similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558400/sql-server-2008-datetime-column-jdbc-insert-problem) and lots of questions regarding SQL itself or C#...

Here is what I am seeing:

```
MapSqlParameterSource parameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        //parameterSource.addValue( "insertDate", DateTime.now().minusHours( 1 ).toGregorianCalendar(), Types.TIME );
        parameterSource.addValue( "insertDate", new Timestamp( DateTime.now().minusHours( 1 ).getMillis() ) );

        List< String > contents =
            _simpleJdbcTemplate
                .query(
                    "SELECT TOP (200) inserteddatetime, Contents FROM dbo.tsomeTable WHERE (ServiceName = 'something') and inserteddatetime > :insertDate",
                    new RowMapper< String >() {
                        @Override
                        public String mapRow( final ResultSet rs, final int rowNum ) throws SQLException {
                            System.out.println( rs.getTimestamp( "inserteddatetime" ) );

                            return rs.getString( "Contents" );
                        }
                    }, parameterSource );
```

The query "hangs"\does nothing\never returns if:

1. I use the uncommented Timestamp object (as presented above)
2. I replace the `parameterSource` object with `DateTime.now().minusHours( 1 ).toGregorianCalendar()` or `DateTime.now().minusHours( 1 ).toGregorianCalendar().getTime()`
3. I try the commented out line, but change the type to `Timestamp`

So, here is my question or questions...

Is there a known bug\issue with querying on datetime columns in sql server?

Why do I have to use `Time` and not `Timestamp`?

I suspect that Spring is converting the date objects over to `Timestamp` when I query with the object directly (as demonstrated in #2).

Comment: I've developed several applications backed by SQLServer 2005/2008 and date/time queries/columns work fine.  It will be helpful to include the ddl you used to create the table (for the column type of insertedDatetime).

Comment: The hanging/never returning sounds suspect to me. Can you run a Sql Server trace and see what it is doing? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175047.aspx Also, can you confirm that you are using a datetime column with insertDate and not a TIMESTAMP?

Answer (score 1):

1. `TIMESTAMP` is a server-generated value used to help with `data consistency`, its not a simple data type, so for `storing datetime value`, avoid TIMESTAMP datatype.
2. Also, SQL Server TIMESTAMP is `confusing`, and it's `deprecated`. It is replaced by the `ROWVERSION keyword`, which should reduce confusion.